# Laravel 5 use() path

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to use this package: https://github.com/spatie/calendar-links

The simple example is as follows:

```
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2018-02-01 09:00');
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2018-02-01 18:00');

$link = Link::create('Sebastian\'s birthday', $from, $to)
->description('Cookies & cocktails!')
->address('Samberstraat 69D, 2060 Antwerpen');

// Generate a link to create an event on Google calendar
echo $link->google();

// Generate a link to create an event on Yahoo calendar
echo $link->yahoo();

// Generate a data uri for an ics file (for iCal & Outlook)
echo $link->ics();
```

When running this in a Controller I got the following error:

`Class Link not found`

As I hadn't imported it via `use()`.

So I then tried the following:

- use Spatie\CalendarLinks\Link;
- \use Spatie\CalendarLinks\Link;

I still received the same error.

How do you define the path within the use statement?

The path to the class I want is:

`\vendor\spatie\calendar-links\src\Link.php`

In many examples, I've seen that other packages have Aliases but when they do not, how do you properly reference them?

Comment: `use` does not load the file and has nothing to do with file paths, it just aliases (typically *shortens*) a namespaced name. Are you including the vendor autoloader somewhere…?

Comment: Have you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: So use doesn't point to a path? It just makes it so I can use it as Link rather than the full path? If so, how do you tell Aravel where it is when you have no allias or service provider?

Comment: Did you load this through composer or did you install this manually? Should be able to do a install through composer and then do a dumpautoload.

Comment: I installed via Composer

Comment: It was dump-autoload :/ Should you run that command each time you install a package?